# How to have link fragment also scroll to top of page in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a single-page-app with Angular and I'm having an issue with my link fragments:

```
<a href="/#/search">Search</a>
```

Clicking here takes me to the right page but retains my scroll position. I would like for it to scroll to the top of the page, so my current work-around is:

```
<a href="" ng-click="goToSearch()">Search</a>
```

And inside the controller:

```
$scope.goToSearch = function() {
    $location.path("/search");
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
}
```

Is there a more straight forward way to do this? I have 4-5 of these links and have to put a function similar to goToSearch in multiple controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AngularUI Router, you need to set the *autoscroll* attribute of the ui-view element to **false**.

```
<div ui-view="myview" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

Source: [http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive%3aui-view)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help http://www.doodlekit.com/blog/entry/55645/auto-scroll-down-links-internal-anchors#toplink

Assuming that the view  you are linking to also has a link